# Interpreting special case of 'x for x in ...' loop in python

Tags: python

I have a question about the code chunk below:

```
for i, name in enumerate([x[:-3] for x in dm_cov.columns[:10]]):
    stats['beta'][i].write(f'../data/{sub}_beta_{name}.nii.gz')
```

Is it accurate to say that the above code chunk is functionally equivalent to the code chunk below?

```
for i, name in enumerate([x for x in dm_cov.columns[:7]]):
    stats['beta'][i].write(f'../data/{sub}_beta_{name}.nii.gz')
```

I'm curious because `x` should be a column name, so I'm not sure how it can be subsetted with `[:-3]`.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think only a "column name" is valid in that position, or that this is any kind of special case?

Comment: What is `dm_cov`. A Pandas dataframe? Why not `enumerate(dm_cov.columns[:7])`?

Comment: No, those don't look equivalent at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the two snippets are not equivalent. `dm_cov.columns[:10]` gives the first ten column names.

`x[:-3] for x in ...` then slices out the last three characters of each column name given by `dm_cov.columns[:10]`.

Your second snippet `[x for x in dm_cov.columns[:7]]` just takes the first seven column names in their entirety.

By the way, that list comprehension is useless in the second snippet, you could just `enumerate(dm_cov.columns[:7])`

You can verify this by using a different iterable instead of `dm_cov.columns`:

```
test = [f"data{i}_col" for i in range(15)]
# ['data0_col', 'data1_col', 'data2_col', 'data3_col', 'data4_col', 'data5_col', 'data6_col', 'data7_col', 'data8_col', 'data9_col', 'data10_col', 'data11_col', 'data12_col', 'data13_col', 'data14_col']

print([x[:-3] for x in test[:10]])
# ['data0_', 'data1_', 'data2_', 'data3_', 'data4_', 'data5_', 'data6_', 'data7_', 'data8_', 'data9_']

print([x for x in test[:7]])
# ['data0_col', 'data1_col', 'data2_col', 'data3_col', 'data4_col', 'data5_col', 'data6_col']
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `columns` to a iterable and compare the differences:

```py
columns = [
    'january', 'february', 'march', 'april',
    'may', 'june', 'july', 'august',
    'september', 'october', 'november', 'december',
]

for i, name in enumerate([x[:-3] for x in columns[:10]]):
    print(name)
    # janu
    # febru
    # ma
    # ap
    #
    # j
    # j
    # aug
    # septem
    # octo
    # > Only the first 10 elements, without the last 3 letters each
    
for i, name in enumerate([x for x in columns[:7]]):
    print(name)
    # january
    # february
    # march
    # april
    # may
    # june
    # july
    # > Only the first 7 elements
```

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not equivalent at all.

If `x` is a column name, `x[:-3]` is the column name with the last 3 characters removed. The second version of the code doesn't remove the last 3 characters.

The first version iterates through the first 10 column names, the second version iterates through only the first 7 column names.

You seem to have assumed that the two slices are operating at the same level, so you can combine the end indexes. But one slice is operating on the list of names, the other is operating on each name.